# How to make a regular expression case insensitive?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am working on a Drupal Commerce shipping rule and it needs a regular expression to compare postcodes with the buyers address as below;

```
/^AB37|^AB38|^AB41/
```

I am finding this code to be case sensitive and I need it to be more relaxed allowing lowercase or mixed.

I have read I need a 'i' flag, but I am unsure how to apply this.

Could somebody please provide me with an example?

Comment: Yes that's spot on, you use an `i` flag: `/^AB37|^AB38|^AB41/i`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I realise the question may be fairly general, but it is specifically about a common use case for commerce_shipping so I would argue that it is not off topic.

Comment: @Clive I tried your suggestion without success I'm afraid - the rule is not triggered at all. The field help text reads:  'A regular expression ("/(35|38)[0-9]{3}/") or comma-separated list, including ranges ("98, 100:200")'

Comment: The `i` flag comes at the end. You can test your rule using this tool: https://regexr.com/ - otherwise I'd argue DC is wrong here if it won't accept a valid regex.

Comment: @Kevin DC doesn't seem to accept a comma separated list of postcodes either. Hence try with regex. Maybe a bug

Comment: Yes that sounds fair enough @MrPaulDriver, sorry for closing prematurely

Answer (score 0):

The case insensitive usually is adding a "i" char after the delimiter bar, something like this:
/^AB37|^AB38|^AB41/i

but depends of the case it can be changed. In JS, for example is adding a new param (`var re = new RegExp(myVar,"ig")`) or in php is `preg_match("[expression]i", $text, $matches);`